# How do I find a list of closed questions at EL&U?

Tags: support, closed-questions, search

Simply put, I should like to see whether there is any closed question that has something in it meriting a reopen vote. How do I find the list of closed questions here?

Comment: Go to the search bar. Type `closed:1`. Pick your sort (eg *by votes*, *by newest*). Voila.

Comment: Voila indeed! Thanks a lot for the lightning-quick reply @Dan Bron: I am saving your comment as an answer here and I hope other users will also take some time to see if there are any closed questions worth reopening.

Comment: @Mari-lou A very true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the search term [`closed:yes`](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes) (or as Dan Bron suggests, `closed:1`).

The Search page itself contains some tips when you click the 'Advanced Search Tips' link on the right:

[image]

You can use it e.g. to exclude questions which are closed as duplicates.

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel for the 'advanced' useful information!

Answer (score 1):

I am pasting Dan Bron's very helpful comment as an answer here because a comment can disappear anytime:

> Go to the search bar. Type closed:1. Pick your sort (eg by votes, by newest). Voila

Comment: I used this search method and got the list of closed questions: so many questions deservedly closed according to off-topic guidelines *just in the last 36 hours* and hardly any one of them deserving a reopen vote at present: OMG it's mind-blowing and I salute the dedicated members tirelessly casting votes *correctly* to close off-topic questions here at EL & U.

Comment: I remember from a Meta Stack Exchange question that EL&U has one of the highest % of closed questions (close to 50% I believe) in the network. I can't find the reference, unfortunately.

Comment: @Glorfindel does that include questions that have been migrated (to ELL)?

Comment: I don't remember.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Of those (now) 22,277 142 were migrated here. (Search on closed:yes migrated:yes)

Comment: @Stoney B -- very true; and somebody might say that 142 migrated out of 22000+ closed is a *miniscule* proportion: but out of those 142 migrations in 6 years, over 100 have occurred in the last 40 days, since June 2, 2017 -- this is *very* encouraging for members like myself who have been campaigning from time to time for 'more consistently' migrating *more* deserving questions to ELL. I daresay such recent consciousness-raising about migration has contributed to members exercising the option more often, thus solving my 3 months-old complaint that *'not enough Q's are being migrated to ELL.'*

Comment: @marcellothearcane note too that 142 is the number of 'closed and migrated questions' -- if you search 'migrated:yes' only (all migrated questions regardless of closure) you will find that around 730 questions have been migrated, mainly to ELL, over the years, of which nearly 115 were migrated in the 2 months since 12 May 2017.